# Considerations regarding hamburger menu in HP and traditional menu in subpages, for desktop

Tags: website-design, navigation, menu, mega-menu

I know hamburger menus in desktop are not optimal but our team is stuck with it. Therefore, we wanted implement a normal main nav for subpages, which will result in a inconsistent experience.

Wanted to ask for any opinions or considerations for this approach, or examples of acceptable executions.

[image]

Comment: Can u provide screenshots and more details. Will the subpages be ones that were selected from the hamburger menu? so the hamburger menu is on the main page?

Comment: yup, just added

Comment: Using hamburgers may be suboptimal on desktop, but my personal opinion would be that to have two completely different nav systems between the top level and the children pages seems like it might end up being way more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display the subpages' nav items **vertically** on the **same side** of the page where the hamburger menu items display.

This way you do not switch from a hamburger (vertical) design on the main page to a horizontal design on the subpages. Users will still find the nav items on the same side of the page. This keeps it as **consistent** as possible considering that you can do nothing about the hamburger menu.

[image: Homepage with Hamburger menu]

[image: Subpage with vertical nav items]